# Entity Framework Associations

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've created a Model with Entity Framework from three database tables:

1. Agents
2. AgentsGroups
3. Groups

AgentsGroups is a simple table with three columns: 1 id and two foreign keys linking Agents and Groups (every Agent can have multiple Groups). Pretty basic stuff.

Entity Framework correctly recognizes the relationships between the table. Now, with LINQPad I am able to get the names of all the groups associated with an agent starting from the agent ID:

```
from a in Agents
    join ag in AgentsGroups on a.Code equals ag.AgentCode
    join g in Groups on ag.GroupCode equals g.Code
    where a.Code == 10199
    select g.Name
```

This, though, doesn't work on the very program as, in fact, AgentCode and GroupCode are mapped as Associations, not fields.

I guess I have to use Include, but I've never used it, so the help requested is: how could I translate the given semi-working linq expression in a similar expression giving out the Group Names but using Associations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear why the query as given would not work. What exactly is the problem you get?

Answer (score 2):

Much simpler in EF:

```
from a in Agents
where a.Code == 10199
from g in a.Groups
select g.Name
```

You almost never use join in EF.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but the given expression  gave me ALL the rows in group.. where is the association? is it meant to be implicit?

Comment: Look carefully at the qualifiers (a., for example). It's not implicit, just small. I was guessing on the association property name; you may have called it something else.